# Restore offloaded audio recording app not in the store anymore from daughters iPad

Tags: iphone, ipad, itunes, time-machine, audio

I have the iPad backed up to a MacBook Pro, iTunes sync I think, and probably in time machine.

Also have a snow leopard machine if older is of any use.

Need to get the audio that's still sitting on her iPad somehow, it would mean the most to us both.

Gotta be a way since it's well still there.

Comment: There are 3rd party utilities like iMazing that can extract data from an iOS backup. And I think they have a free trial period too...

Comment: I did used once AnyTrans for free using the trial period as spotted by @SteveChambers